# Python snowflake connection error because of spaces in query

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I am trying to run a sql query in my python notebook,

code in cell looks like

```
sql = "select date, count(distinct id)
from table
group by 1;"
```

When I run I get an error of

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 1)
```

I think I found the error, when I delete the space between the lines it goes away and runs such as:

```
"select date, count(distinct id) from table group by 1;"
```

The problem is thats my sample query, but I have large queries where it gets difficult to backspace them into one line, is there a way where I can get this to run without having on one line? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can triple quotes and not double: “”” string””” or ”’ string”’
This will allow you to have your query on seperate lines rather that one line. For example, if you have a large query, you can have it go on multiple lines

```
sql = """SELECT *
         FROM TABLE
         WHERE 1=1
         AND stuff = stuff"""
```

Answer (score 2):

In python, you can create multi line strings using triple quotes `"""`.
For example, this will raise a SyntaxError:

```
string = "hello
there"
```

but this won't:

```
string = """hello
there"""
```